# Content from PDF file missing upon print

Tags: printing, adobe-acrobat

[image]

I had to print this document using a specific computer and version of acrobat as the colour of the printouts will be different if i do otherwise.

I had the same boxes only on the last two pages. Version of Windows is XP Professional and acrobat is running on 8.1 Tried updating and reinstalling acrobat but to no avail. the document seems fine on other computers but I can only print from the one above.
Any help and advise is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I have edited your question and included the pic, but what does this have to do with 'pages missing'? Please edit your question to make itclearer.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, what a mess! Try to edit the document using the tips from this tutorial
http://www.askwiki.net/How-to-Edit-a-Pdf
Some of these tips can help.
If the problem persists, try to use someone else's computer with updated software

Comment: Could you make a short summary in the answer of the article referred? The ideology of Superuser is to contain full information in the answer, e.g. if the source article is taken offline.

Answer (score 0):

In the print-menu (probably somewhere in the advanced print menu) is a flag "print as picture". Try it.

Comment: This would be more helpful with screenshots or an exact path to the option